# Model Deforms after applied the Mirror modifier

Tags: modifiers, rigging, mirror

I just applied the mirror modifire to move forward to the shapekeys but everytime when i try to move the mesh then the applied side from the mirror modifire deforms without selecting it.[image]

Comment: Do you have the x-mirror option enabled int he toolbar options tab? Also if you apply the rotation of your object in object mode does that affect how it deforms?

Comment: Oh yes it was the X-mirror thank you very much for the fast answer :DDDDDD

Comment: I just posted the solution as an answer. Can you accept the answer so that this question is solved?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the x mirror option enabled in the options tab of the toolbar. My guess would also be that to have the option behave that way your rotation should be applied as well, but just disabling the x mirror should fix it.